# Using chef-metal with Windows-7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to use chef-metal with on my windows workstation. Following are details of my setup :
OS : Windows 7, 32-bit
Chef client version : 11.12.0

I follow the instructions as mentioned  [here](https://github.com/opscode/chef-metal) . I intend to use the Vagrant driver for chef-metal, so I have vagrant and virtualbox installed on my system. Next as the documentation says, I install 'chef-metal' gem, and then try to run the basic vagrant_linux and simple recipes. But the setup is giving me rubygems conflicts for gem 'ffi', the error is shown in the screenshot below :
Apparently, installing chef-metal gem is messing up my chef-client installation also. If I run chef-client -v, just to check if chef-client is working fine, i throws the same gem conflict error.

[image]

While installation of chef-metal gem, I observe that it is installing certain gems, that are already installed on the system(with the chef-client installation.) I tried to uninstalling a version of the gem throwing the error(ffi-1.9.3-x86-mingw32), but it showed me this info:

[image]

Same is the response i get when i try to uninstall ffi-1.5.0-x86-mingw32 gem.

Update :

As per Tensibai's suggestions, I removed teh older version of the gem and updated to use a new one. Following is the new gem dependency error I get :
[image]

Please help as I have reached a dead end on searching a solution for this one:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gem documentation is [HERE](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-uninstall)

To uninstall it is `gem uninstall ffi -v 1.5.0`

What the errors tells you is that it can't load it because ffi is in versino 1.5 and ohai require it in a version around 1.9.X (the ~> 1.9).

You best bet to resolve the problem is to run a `gem update ffi -v 1.9.3`

And update chef too to remove old depending: gem update chef

Comment: Yup. tried the same uninstallation command, then only it showd me above message. Regarding the update command, the response is '220 OK, Nothing to update'. But still the problem pertains

Comment: Your screenshot shows something different without the use of -v

Comment: Oops, my bad. I missed the '-v' there. So, now I have uninstalled the older version of the gem, thanks to you. Also, updated with the second command. It now shows dependencies error(screenshot updated in the question.)

Comment: Updated answer too, but did not check the overlaps between chef and chef metal